# is vector reallocation and vector::push_back required by the standard to use placement new and copy constructor?

Tags: c++, stl

Putting aside the move semantics at this moment, is vector reallocation and vector::push_back required by the standard to use placement new and copy constructor? If so where does it in the standard say so?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["CopyConstructible" requirement for C++ stl container element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532173/copyconstructible-requirement-for-c-stl-container-element)

Comment: Well it is not exactly the same question, but I think you will find there everything that you are looking for.

Comment: Apologize if I duplicated. But my understanding is that "CopyConstructible" is a requirement which the implementation does not necessarily actually use.

Comment: not an answer, but: with a possibly throwing move constructor it's unsafe to move items from old buffer to new. one might get a failure situation impossible to recover from. so the question then is, is `std::vector` at all *permitted* to move instead of copying?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.  Vector, like all other containers, is required to
use `allocator_traits<allocator_type>::construct` and
`allocator_traits<allocator_type>::destroy` (§23.2.1/3) and to
obtain all memory using the allocator (§23.2.1/7).  If you
provide a custom allocator, you can do just about anything.  The
default allocator is required to call `::operator new`
(§20.6.9.1/6) and to use placement new (§20.6.9.1/12).

Comment: It seems that this answer doesn't discuss the question about whether copy constructor is required to be used?

Comment: @Alf Good point.  I forgot to mention that.  But is it necesary; if the library copies something, the copy constructor will be used.  Except that it's used through placement new, if you're using the standard allocator, and through whatever you've provided otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

> **C++11 §23.3.6.3**, about `std::vector::reserve`:
>
> “If an exception is thrown other than by the move constructor of a non-`CopyInsertable` type, there are no effects.”

This means that for buffer reallocation with a non-`CopyInsertable` item type, an implemention is free to *move* items from the old buffer to the new one, if possible, then not using the type’s copy constructor.

The effect of an exception from a move constructor is left unspecified in the paragraph quoted above, and this is made explicit in §23.3.6.5 about `insert` and `push_back`: “ If an exception is thrown by the move constructor of a non-`CopyInsertable` `T`, the effects are unspecified.”

Use of placement new is implied because that’s the language’s only feature to construct an object in pre-existing storage. As James Kanze notes in his answer, it’s also explicitly required via the requirements on allocators, and by §23.2.1/2 requirement that the allocator’s `construct` method be used.