# What are the requirements for container element type in STDLIB?

Tags: c++, c++11, containers

One thing I know,may not be true, is that the `T` should be **copy-constructible**, that is, the `T` should have an accessible copy constructor.

However,is there any other requirements,like **copy assignable**?

As a complement, I remember that the **Effective STL** says `vector<bool>` is not a standard container because it doesn't meet the requirement of `T *p=&c[0]` being well-formed.

Comment: Are you referring to [this](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements)? and what type of container are you asking?

Comment: @codekaizer Rules for all types of containers. For example, all containers require `T` to be **copy constructible**.

Comment: It is not true that all containers require T to be copy constructible

Comment: @M.M I read that requirement from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6532173/copyconstructible-requirement-for-c-stl-container-element).

Comment: @bigxiao the asker of that question incorrectly cites the standard

Comment: @M.M What does standard actually say about that ? I found the requirement of **copy-insertable** from [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Container)(At the bottom of the linked page) . And  I thought **copy-insertable** == **copy-constructible**.

Comment: @bigxiao, CopyInsertable is a different concept. It is not part of the requirments of the `value_type` of Containers.

Comment: @RSahu In [this page](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/container.requirements) it seems that since the standard require that every container should have `X(a)`, so `T` should be **copy insertable**.

Comment: @codekaizer Does all standard containers need to meet the requirements and implement all APIs in that table?

Comment: @bigxiao I think you misinterpret the Standard. It effectively says that the expression `X(a)` is well formed, if `T` is `CopyInsertable` into `X`. If not, you cannot copy-construct a container `X<T>`. A trivial example: `std::vector<std::thread> v1; std::vector<std::thread> v2(v1);` throws an error, since `std::thread` has deleted copy constructor. Thus, you can have a `vector` of `thread`s, but you cannot copy such a vector.

Comment: @DanielLangr So does that mean there are no compulsive requirements for all containers?

Comment: @bigxiao No, I just responded to your comment. However, I believe there are some requirements common to all the containers from Standard library. At least those that have no _Assertion/note  pre-/post-condition_ in the table. Such as expression `a.begin()`; all the containers must implement member function `begin`, which you can consider as a _requirement_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there are different requirements for sequence containers and associative containers. For example, following is for vector(see cppreference.com for more details). Also, note that it has been changed with newer version of c++.

> - T must meet the requirements of CopyAssignable and CopyConstructible.   (until C++11)
> - The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is
>     required that element type is a complete type and meets the
>     requirements of Erasable, but many member functions impose stricter
>     requirements. (since C++11) (until C++17)
> - The requirements that are imposed on the elements depend on the actual operations performed on the container. Generally, it is
>     required that element type meets the requirements of Erasable, but
>     many member functions impose stricter requirements. This container
>     (but not its members) can be instantiated with an incomplete element
>     type if the allocator satisfies the allocator completeness
>     requirements. (since C++17)

Comment: Is copyconstrucible==copyinsertable?

Comment: @bigxiao If they were, they wouldn't be two different concepts. With `CopyInsertable` concept, allocators come into play. See this answer for some details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14916142/580083.