# What is the difference between equivalence and equality?

Tags: c++, equality, equivalence

What is the difference between equivalence and equality in C++?

There is a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311936/what-is-the-difference-between-equality-and-equivalence). However, this question is tagged with [math](/questions/tagged/math), while I am interested in the meaning in C++ context.

To see the terms in context: Scott Meyers uses them in an example in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tg1ONG18H8).

Comment: The video is not available anymore. Probably, [this](https://youtu.be/TdajK_SXwoc?t=1690) is a video of the same talk.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

On [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_comparison) i found the following quote:

> For the types that are both EqualityComparable and LessThanComparable, the C++ standard library makes a distinction between equality, which is the value of the expression a == b and equivalence, which is the value of the expression !(a < b) && !(b < a).

Comment: More generally, for each `Compare comp` you can synthesise an equivalence `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`. There is only one "equality", but there can be any number of "equivalences"