# Use C++20 Concept to constrain template parameter

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

I want to use concepts to replace a design which currently uses SFINAE (enable_if). To simplify, I have created a simpler example which shows an identical problem:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept smallerThanPointer = sizeof(T) < sizeof(void*);

template<typename T>
concept notSmallerThanPointer = !smallerThanPointer<T>;


template<smallerThanPointer T>
class MyClass
{
 public:
    MyClass() { std::cout << "MyClass[smallerThanPointer]\n"; }
};

template<notSmallerThanPointer T>
class MyClass
{
 public:
    MyClass() { std::cout << "MyClass[...]\n"; }
};


int main()
{
    MyClass<int[8]> c1;

    return 0;
}
```

But my compiler (g++-11) will not accept this syntax because it thinks I'm redeclaring `MyClass`. Also this example is not possible:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class MyClass requires smallerThanPointer<T>
{
 public:
    MyClass() { std::cout << "MyClass[smallerThanPointer]\n"; }
};

template<typename T>
class MyClass
{
 public:
    MyClass() { std::cout << "MyClass[...]\n"; }
};
```

All examples I have found online with concepts only discuss how to apply concepts to function parameters. So is it possible at all to do with a class?

Comment: `requires` can go immediately after the template parameter list; for functions only, it can also go after the (ordinary) parameter list because it’s sometimes easier to phrase constraints in terms of parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax for the partial template specialization for constraints should be:

```cpp
template<typename T>
concept smallerThanPointer = sizeof(T) < sizeof(void*);
    
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { std::cout << "MyClass[...]\n"; }
};
    
template<class T> requires smallerThanPointer<T>
class MyClass<T>
{
public:
    MyClass() { std::cout << "MyClass[smallerThanPointer]\n"; }
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/ex6x3W9xr)

Comment: `template<smallerThanPointer T>` as you originally had it also works for the specialization and is a bit more concise.

Comment: @NathanPierson. Yes, but I tried to follow OP's style.